# System.OverflowException when casting a System.IntPtr to a uint

Tags: c#, overflowexception

I tried to save the `MaximumApplicationAddress` from `SystemInfo` into an `uint`, but I get a `System Overflow Exception`:

> **System.OverflowException:** The arithmetic operation caused an overflow

I tried a lot and also googled a lot, but nothing helps. If I convert or if I use an decimal, nothing helped.

Here is the problematic code:

```
private uint _maxAddress;

public MemorySearch()
{
    SystemInfo info;
    GetSystemInfo(out info);

    // This line throws a System.OverflowException:
    _maxAddress = (uint)info.MaximumApplicationAddress;
    resetFields();
}
```

[Full Source Code Here](https://pastebin.com/nzR7g9UD)

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: It is generally bad practice to post source code screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is telling you that the size of `MaximumApplicationAddress` is larger than a `uint`.

Try using a `long` (64-bit integer) instead:

```
private long _maxAddress;

public MemorySearch()
{
    SystemInfo info;
    GetSystemInfo(out info);

    _maxAddress = info.MaximumApplicationAddress.ToInt64();
    resetFields();
}
```

Comment: The variable watch pane shows that the value of `MaximumApplicationAddress` is `0x00007ffffffeffff` (which is `140,737,488,289,791` in base-10). This is out of range for [uint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/uint). Store value in a [long](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/long).

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit or implicit conversion from `IntPtr` to `uint` (`UInt32`). There is an explicit conversion to `Int32`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr.op_explicit?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IntPtr_op_Explicit_System_IntPtr__System_Int32.

That function throws `OverflowException` if you call it on a 64-bit system.

If you really want to turn your 64-bit pointer into a 32-bit value, then you'll have to cast to a `ulong`, and then to a `uint`.